# Java Memory Model happens-before guarantees for Thread Pool interactions

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, java-memory-model

Does Java Memory Model provide happens-before guarantee for Thread Pool interactions? In particular, *will writes made by a thread pool worker thread before the end of running an item from a work queue be visible to a worker thread running the next item from the queue after that?*

The specification (I personally find this FAQ useful: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#synchronization) states that "*A call to start() on a thread happens before any actions in the started thread.*" or simply put, any memory writes you make before starting a thread will be executed before and visible to the run() method the started thread is going to execute. It is different for a thread pool, the start() would normally run before you make a write. Consider a simple workflow where a context object is mutated and passed to the next action:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    private static class Container<T> {
        private T value;
        public T get() {
            return value;
        }
        public void set(T newValue) {
            value = newValue;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Container<Integer> sharedObject = new Container<>();
        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        // SKIPPED: pre-warm the executor so all worker threads are start()'ed
        final Runnable read = () -> System.out.println("Got " + sharedObject.get());
        Runnable write = () -> {
            sharedObject.set(35);
            executor.execute(read);
        };
        executor.execute(write);
        // SKIPPED: wait until done
    }
}
```

Is the write to `sharedObject.value` by `write.run()` guaranteed to be visible (not asking about ordering, this is obvious) to `read.run()`?

(PS: I understand that making `value` `volatile` does provide this guarantee)

**Update (complements the answer):** 
Package summary documentation for `java.util.concurrent` summarizes memory consistency guarantees provided by the language and extended by the framework: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that it is guaranteed to be visible.  `ExecutorService` extends `Executor`, and the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) for `Executor` say:

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to submitting a `Runnable` object to an `Executor` *happen-before* its execution begins, perhaps in another thread.

By my reading, that matches what is going on in your example.  The `write` runnable is submitting the `read` runnable, so there is a *happens-before* relationship between events before the submission in the `write` thread (i.e. the `set` call) and the events afterwards in the `read` thread (i.e. the `get` call).

The fact that the `write` runnable is itself submitted means that there is also a *happens-before* between the creation of the `Container` object and the call to `set`.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting javadoc of [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a `Runnable` or `Callable` task to an `ExecutorService` *happen-before* any actions taken by that task, which in turn *happen-before* the result is retrieved via `Future.get()`.

But, it says nothing about two tasks added to the queue, and whether processing of task 1 happens-before processing of task 2, as seen from the task. Only that adding the task to the queue happens before the task processing it, and the task execution happens before the result is retrieved by the original invoker.

**Update**

There is no happens-before correlation between two different, independently submitted tasks, even if somehow one is known the run to completion before the other begins running.

Of course, when one task submits another, as is done in the question, any action taken in task 1 *before* it submits task 2, *will* happen-before the execution of task 2.

If task 1 continues to do other stuff after submitting task 2, there is of course no happen-before guarantee, because task 2 may run and complete before task 1 gets to continue it's work.

Comment: I don't follow you - your conclusion is opposite to the quote you used... In the op's example, there definitely is a hb relationship between `sharedObject.set(35)` and the `println`. Maybe you missed the fact that the second task is added to the queue *from the first task*, not in the main thread.

Comment: @assylias You're right, I did miss that fact. As the wording of my answer would suggest, I am talking about two independently added tasks, not one task submitting another.

Comment: Thanks for noticing an mismatch between my question and the example. Example is what I wanted to know about but could not figure out the question, it would've been: are write actions in `write` made before submitting `read` visible to `read`'s thread.